# Complex alignment situation in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a complicated alignment situation, which I was hoping there was some solution with `alignmentGuide`s, but I can't figure it out.

I need to align the following list of entries (in a mono font), such that as a group it is horizontally centered.

[image]

***But also*** that it is positioned the same way, and aligned the same way along the leading edge, even if one of the entries in a row is longer:

[image]

I don't want to hardcode any sizing or positioning values.

Here's some simple code to replicate:

```
struct TestView: View {

    let values: [(String, String)] = [
        ("03", "30.123"),
        ("02", "33.222"),
        ("01", "completed")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(values, id: \.1) { tuple in 
                HStack(spacing: 24) {
                    Text(tuple.0)
                    Text(tuple.1)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 250) // to simulate outer container dimensions
    }
}
```

Comment: I see 2 photos in your question, are them your goal?

Comment: @swiftPunk, yes

Comment: Ok, I think you are coding for macOS right? and why LazyVStack? VStack would work good, do you have ton's of data?

Comment: @swiftPunk. for iOS... `LazyVStack` behaves differently than `VStack` - it expands horizontally, whereas VStack hugs the content (at least, that's what I observed)

Comment: Yes, I want to know if you have to use LazyVStack? because I see no need to use Lazy one in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way may it help:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TestView()

    }
    
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    let values: [(String, String)] = [
        ("03", "30.123"),
        ("02", "33.222"),
        ("01", "completed")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 24) {
            
            VStack { ForEach(values, id: \.1) { tuple in Text(tuple.0) } }

            VStack(alignment: .leading) { ForEach(values, id: \.1) { tuple in

                Text("00.000")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                    .overlay(Text(tuple.1).lineLimit(1).fixedSize(), alignment: .leading)
  
            } }
            
        }
        .font(Font.system(.body, design: .monospaced))
        .padding(5.0)
        .background(Color.pink.opacity(0.5).cornerRadius(5.0))

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the crucial difference with your solution is that it positions slight to the left of where it would be if the last entry was not `("01", "completed")`, but another number, like `("01", "31.321")` - which is the key point of this question. In other words, the longer "completed" makes the entire `HStack` wider, which causes it to shift a bit around the center

Comment: Can you explain more? I can update my code for your design no problem, what is the limits or freedom in your project?

Comment: Look at the second image in my question as compared to the first. The text in both the images are exactly aligned on the leading edge, despite the second image having a wider bottom row. That's what I want, and that's not what will happen with your answer.

Comment: If I understand you right your base design is stand on `("00", "00.000")`, and if some texts get longer then it not allowed to change the position of the view? right?

Comment: Correct... A placeholder (or if you want, a first like) has to be horizontally centered inside the container, but the following likes have to be aligned with it, even if they are longer.

Comment: I think I can solve the issue, I update my answer.

Comment: @NewDev: I just updated my answer, hope to cover what you need.

Comment: The last solution seems to work. Why do you need the `if tuple.1.count < 7`? Can you not just use whatever is in the `else` - it seems to work just as well.

Comment: Oh yeah! It makes sense! thanks, updated!

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out and see if it holds. Also, I'd suggest removing the old `TestView` to make the answer more to the point.

Comment: Of course! the reason that I used If and else to give less work to CPU! But since it is just few line code it does not make big deference.

Answer (score 0):

I found *a* way to solve this, though it seems quite convoluted to me. Posting here, but still would love a better solution.

The idea was to use a placeholder with dummy content (relying on the fact that this was a monospaced font) and using `anchorPreference` to align around its leading edge.

```
struct LeadingPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
   static var defaultValue: Anchor<CGPoint>? = nil
    
   static func reduce(value: inout Anchor<CGPoint>?, 
                      nextValue: () -> Anchor<CGPoint>?) {
      value = nextValue()
   }
}
```

Then, set that in `anchorPreference`, and capture it in `overlayPreferenceValue` and position with `offset(x:)`

```
LazyVStack(alignment: .center) {
   row(("00", "00.000")) // placeholder that's center-positioned
      .opacity(0)
      .anchorPreference(key: LeadingPreferenceKey.self,
                        value: .leading, , transform: { $0 })
}
.overlayPreferenceValue(LeadingPreferenceKey.self) { leading in
   GeometryReader { geo in 
      LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
         ForEach(values, id: \.1) { tuple in
            row(tuple)
         }
      }
      .offset(x: leading.map { geo[$0].x } ?? 0)
   }
}
```

```
func row(_ tuple: (String, String)) -> some View {
   HStack(spacing: 24) {
      Text(tuple.0)
      Text(tuple.1)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will provide your alignment as well as control of the width of your columns. It is a separate view that takes a tuple and returns two VStacks in an HStack contained by width:

```
struct TwoItemLeadingAlignedColumn: View {
    let firstColumnItems: [String]
    let secondColumnItems: [String]
    let width: CGFloat?
    
    init(items: [(String, String)], width: CGFloat? = nil) {
        firstColumnItems = items.map { $0.0 }
        secondColumnItems = items.map { $0.1 }
        self.width = width
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ForEach(firstColumnItems, id: \.self) {item in
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.25)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(secondColumnItems, id: \.self) {item in
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        .frame(width: width)
        }
    }
}
    

struct TestView: View {
    
    let values: [(String, String)] = [
        ("03", "30.123"),
        ("02", "33.222"),
        ("01", "completed")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        TwoItemLeadingAlignedColumn(items: values, width: 150)
            .frame(width: 350, height: 250) // to simulate outer container dimensions
    }
}
```

This answer will work whether or not you are using a monospaced font.

Update: Center first column

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically didn't want to hardcode any dimension, which is what you're doing with `frame(width: width)`

Comment: The width was in there so you could control it, however, I made it optional so you can use width or not as you please.

Comment: Have you tested this solution?

Comment: Yes, it suffers from the same issues as @swiftPunk's answer. Try changing "completed" to something longer, and you'll see how the leading edge will move left. That shouldn't happen, which is the key point of my question.

Comment: I updated my answer with a geometry reader and a set percentage of the available space given to the view to be fixed between the columns. The second column now won't move if the amount of text changes. Is this acceptable? Otherwise, you are not going to be able to have a fixed view like you want in SwiftUI without something being fixed in the layout.

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work. It seems to wrap, and I haven't managed to wrangle it into something that works.

Comment: Do you have any other requirement other than not wrapping?